# How primary index works under the hood?

Tags: indexing, rdbms

Let's take some rdbms like Postgresql or Mysql.
And create some table with primary key and primary index on it.
Primary index is intended to speed up *select* operations with clause *where primary_key_column=....*. 
It relies on sorted order by *primary_key_column*.

What I want to clarify is, do the rdbms keep the order of entries sorted?
If not, how can we perform fast select on unordered data?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ - there is a substantial (technical) difference between the PK index in Postgres and the one in MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does database indexing work? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

Comment: Depends on the DBMS, the DDL, etc etc. This question is too broad. Also, nevertheless, when this is clear it will be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. Also what has your research shown? Including from reading the manual of a DBMS & relevant chapters of zillions of textbooks. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Index is created on primary key column and it's structured usually as B+ tree or hashtable. The structure points on table's entries.